# appending the data according "id" : Python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting the "km_difference" data in a dictionary of list format in another list. but i want to get the "km_difference" data inside the first index of list according it's "id".

Any helpful, would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

```
data = ShopOwnerShopDetailsSerializer(garage_qs, many=True, context={'request': request}).data
km_difference = []
for record in data:
    lon = record['lon']
    lat = record['lat']
    lon1 = float(lon)
    lat1 = float(lat)
    km_differ = distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
    km_difference.append({"km_difference":km_differ})
data.append({"km_difference":km_difference})
```

**Result: how i get the data format is:**

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "search_result": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "city_name": "CAIRO",
            "shop_location": "iuaisd,qweqw,qwe",
            "lat": "14.56",
            "lon": "89.90",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "city_name": "CAIRO",
            "shop_location": "iuaisd,qweqw,qwe",
            "lat": "14.56",
            "lon": "89.90",
           
        },
        {
            "km_difference": [
                {
                    "km_difference": 7853.450620509551
                },
                {
                    "km_difference": 7853.450620509551
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expecting: how i want output on this format is:**

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "search_result": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "city_name": "CAIRO",
            "shop_location": "iuaisd,qweqw,qwe",
            "lat": "14.56",
            "lon": "89.90",
            "km_difference": 7853.450620509551
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "city_name": "CAIRO",
            "shop_location": "iuaisd,qweqw,qwe",
            "lat": "14.56",
            "lon": "89.90",
            "km_difference": 7853.450620509551
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your new information to the `record` object and then appending it back to your `data` object.

```py
data = ShopOwnerShopDetailsSerializer(garage_qs, many=True, context={'request': request}).data
km_difference = []
for record in data:
    lon = record['lon']
    lat = record['lat']
    lon1 = float(lon)
    lat1 = float(lat)
    km_differ = distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
    record['km_difference'] = km_differ
    data.append(record)
```